# Check whether 2 languages are Turing recognizable or co-Turing recognizable

Tags: turing-machines, decidable

I have these 2 languages

```
A = {<M> | M is a TM and L(M) contains exactly n strings }
B = {<N> | N is a TM and L(N) contains more than n strings }
```

I believe that these 2 are undecidable, but I am not sure whether they are Turing recognizable or co-Turing recognizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B` is Turing recognizable since we can interleave executions of `M` on all possible input tapes. If more than `n` of the running instances of `M` ever halt-accept, then halt-accept.

We know that `A` cannot be Turing-recognizable because, if it were, the language `B' = {<N> | N is a TM and L(N) contains no more than n strings }` would be Turing-recognizable (we could interleave the execution of recognizers for 1, 2, ..., n and halt-accept if any of those did). That would imply both `B` and `B'` were decidable since `B'` must be co-Turing recognizable.

If `A` were co-Turing recognizable, we could recognize machines that accept a number of strings different than `n`. In particular, let `n = 1`. We can run the recognizer for machines whose languages contain other than `n` strings on a TM constructed to accept `L(M) \ {w}` for every possible string `w`. At each stage, we run one step of all existing machines, then construct a new machine, and repeat, thus interleaving executions and ensuring all TMs eventually get to run arbitrarily many steps.

Assuming `|L(M)| = 1`, exactly one of these TMs will halt-accept (the one that removes the only string in `L(M)`) and the rest will either halt-reject or run forever. Therefore, a recognizer for `|L(M)| != 1` can be used to construct a recognizer for `|L(M)| = 1`. This generalizes to `|L(M)| != k` and `|L(M)| = k` by subtracting all possible sets of `k` input strings.

Therefore, if A were co-Turing recognizable, it would also be Turing recognizable, thus decidable. We already know that's wrong, so we must conclude that A is not co-Turing recognizable; nor is it Turing recognizable.